# django ajax | current в шаблоне постоянно равен 0

Tags: ajax, django

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from index.global_context import isAuth

def administrator(request):
    user = isAuth(request.session.get('email',None), request.session.get('password', None))
    if user and user.role=="Admin":
        print(request.POST.get('current') or "0")
        return render(request, 'administrator.html', {'current':request.POST.get('current') or "0"})
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.administrator, name='administrator')
]
```

administrator.html:

```
{% extends 'wrapper.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'administrator.css' %}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="titleAdministrator" align="center">Админ панель</div><hr color="#666666" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

    <!--Навигация-->
    <div id="selectActionForm" align="right">
        <div id="navigration" align="right">Навигация</div>

        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="select" id="id_select" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <option value="0" selected="selected" hidden="hidden">Выбирите действие</option>
            <option value="1">Добавить куратора</option>
            <option value="2">Добавить школу</option>
            <option value="3">Открыть сезон тестирования</option>
            <option value="4">Добавить тест</option>
            <option value="5">Посмотреть статистику</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Выбрать" style="color:black; cursor: pointer;" id="button_choose">

        <div style="cursor: default;font-size: 0.9vw">
            {% if current == "0" %}
            Выберите действие которое хотите осуществить
            {% elif current == "1" %}
            Добавление нового куратора
            {% elif current == "2" %}
            Добавление новой школы
            {% elif current == "3" %}
            Открытие сезона тестирования
            {% elif current == "4" %}
            Добавление теста
            {% elif current == "5" %}
            Просмотр статистики
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#button_choose").click(function(e) {
        current = $("#id_select option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"/administrator/",
                data:{csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(), current:current},
                success: function(d)
                {
                    alert(current);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

в шаблоне current постоянно равен 0, а в views.py current изменяется..

Comment: Нужно через JsonResponse возвращать данные для аякса.

Comment: я лучше без ajax это сделаю)